# Elements in Vue.JS transition-group are not animating properly on-leave

Tags: vue.js, css-transitions, css-animations, vuejs2

I'm trying to implement android's toast-style component with animation in Vue.js 2.
I have the following css for transitions:

```
.toast-enter-active {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
.toast-enter-to {
    opacity: 1;
}
.toast-leave {
    opacity: 1;
transition: all .7s ease-out;
}
.toast-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

The `toast-enter` transitions look good - the list shifts up and the element fades in, but when an element is removed, for some reason the element to be removed jumps to the bottom and then fades out.

Here is what it looks like: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Legmu20c/1/)

Comment: You can probably use `transition: opacity .7s ease-out;` rather than `all` just in case it is trying to animate some other change

Comment: i tried that already - the issue isn't which parts are animating, the issue is that the top element gets moved to the bottom first, and then removed. it should just get removed.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of it.

Comment: The link to jsFiddle is in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The v-for is simply recycling elements since it's using index as key. I solved it by adding an ID field to each `toast` and using this as key:

Template markup:

```
        <div 
            v-for="(toast, index) in toasts"
            :key="toast.id"
            :class = "['toast',toast.type]"
        >
```

Toasts themselves:

```
        {text:'1 test',type:'info', id:1},
        {text:'2 test',type:'info', id:2},
        {text:'3 test',type:'info', id:3},
```

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Legmu20c/2/)